# Spring java Configuration

Tags: java, spring

The following is my code:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.datastore")
public class ABC {

    @Autowired
    B b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        C c= ctx.getBean(C.class);
        String s = b.getObject();
    }
}
```

The problem with above code is that my `@Autowired` b object is coming
   null. But c is not null. 
Could anyone tell me how to to get B b object too. 
   So that, I can have B Object. Also there is a Config.java file in my 
   application which is configured with @Bean annotations.
 Please help me regarding the same.

Comment: Where do you have defined bean for `class B` ? Where is applicationContext.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Let the class where the main is located implement CommandLineRunner and ensure that it is a bean (f.e.: annotated with @Component). And do whatever you want in the run method.

For an example see https://mhdevelopment.wordpress.com/2014/02/09/bootstrap-an-application-with-spring-boot-part1-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

Class `ABC` also needs the `@Component` annotation.